# The underlying provider failed on Open. Connection Timeout Expired

Tags: sql-server, azure

> The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login
>   handshake acknowledgement
>   This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=30;
>   handshake=15004;  The wait operation timed out

infamous pre-login error. it worked before in the same environment and **suddenly stopped**, pretty sure it's a side effect at database vm level, looking for ideas for investigation before pinging microsoft with premier tickets. our firewall team, even by monitoring didn't spotted any loophole.

context

- azure app service windows (appservice) : **connection worked for months**
- appservice webjob toward an mssql database (databaseA) hosted on a vm in azure
- appservice connected to a vnet
- appservice able to connect to other databases (mssql in private datacenter)
- webjob & ssms to databaseA working from local dev laptop
- database on static 1433

[image]

- successful tcpping on azure console

[image]

any idea where to find more detailled log which could explained the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with support of microsoft, we were able to pin point the issue. here some recap for the community and my future me.

connection was interrupted during the 3 way handshake process

- client send a SYN packet
- sql instance respond with ACK SYN

  - after several unsuccesful attempts, sql instance send a RESET packet

network

- x.x.224.8 app service
- 6.x.x.18 sql server

packets

1. SYN
2. ACK SYNC
3. RESET

[image]

in our situation, the SYN.ACK seemed to be dropped by a network device

with wireshark, it was then possible to see the MAC address of the device dropping the ACK SYN. 
following the breabcrumb from there allowed us to spot a missing route for a point-to-site azure VPN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about)